# Why isn't my draggable working?

Tags: jquery-ui

I know dragging works because i can do it on jsfiddle examples, but i'm clearly not doing something right. I have added the html, css and js below but still cant drag the div in chrome. All help appreciated.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='drag.css'></link>
        <script src='drag.js'></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="car">
            <div id="top"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>
            <div id="fwheel"></div>
            <div id="bwheel"></div>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

drag.css

```
#top {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #cc0000;
    left: 25px;
}
#bottom {
    position: relative;
    height:25px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #cc0000;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    top: -25px;
}
#fwheel {
    position: relative;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    top: -35px;
    left: 5px;
}
#bwheel {
    position: relative;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    top: -55px;
    left: 75px;
}
```

drag.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#car').draggable();
});
```

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ybsvgnwk/. Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: Works for me to in the fiddle you posted, I have opened dev tools in chrome and no errors are reported. Could it be something to do with the way I am loading the html file? (just opening it with chrome, not serving it up from node or anything)

Comment: Looks like you are defining a jquery function before including jquery.  Move `<script src='drag.js'></script>` to after the jQuery include.